# Using Label within an SRC to show an image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, label

I have a Label which gets from my database the data "1_1" this is the file name of an image I would like to show relative to the ID.

my image link is

```
<img src="Images/Dropox/.jpg"/>
```

with no file name

I would like to know how to add a label that on load will be populated with the string "1_1" and then for that string to go into my SRC link.

I have tried adding the label into the space required but that doesn't work.

my idea would be something along the lines of

```
  <img src="Images/Dropox/<asp:Label ID="ImageSequencea" runat="server">.jpg"/></asp:Label>
```

or something like that. can anyone help?

thanks!

Comment: so, you want the final result to be <img src="Images/Dropox/1_1.jpg"/> ? is this in a repeater or some other control or just a standard image on the page?

Comment: Show some code on how are you getting data from database and what have you done so far ?

Comment: Are you using a data repeater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Label` corresponds to the `<span>`. Which means that when ASP.NET engine finds a `Label` on the page, it takes its `Text`, wraps into `<span>`, and sends to the output. Most likely you are not looking for:

```
<img src="Images/Dropox/<span>1_1</span>.jpg"/>
```

If you just need url to be `Images/Dropox/1_1.jpg` with `1_1` being inserted at runtime, you can:

1. Just turn your `img` tag into server tag and set its value in code behind:

   ```
   <img id="DropboxImage" runat="server" />
   ```
2. Use scriplet and call function from code behind

   ```
   <img src="Images/Dropox/<%= GetImageName() %>.jpg"/>
   ```
3. User `asp:Image` and set its `ImageUrl` property in code behind:

   ```
   <asp:Image runat="server" ID="DropboxImage" />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<img src="Images/Dropox/<%#Eval("ReturnEntityName")%>.jpg"/></asp:Label>
```